# Singly linked list - push_back

Tags: c, list, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have to create method push_back which will add an item to the end of my list.
But I have one constraint - I can't check if head is empty (if head is null)
I don't have idea how I can do this. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node* next;
};


void print(struct node* head)
{
    struct node* iterator = head;

    while (iterator != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", iterator->value);
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void pushBack(struct node** head, int value)
{
    struct node* element = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* iterator = *head;

    element->value = value;
    element->next = NULL;

    if (iterator == NULL) //can't!
    {
        *head = element;
        return;
    }

    while (iterator->next != NULL)
    {
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    iterator->next = element;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct node* head = NULL;

    pushBack(&head, 4);
    pushBack(&head, 5);
    pushBack(&head, 52);
    pushBack(&head, 1);

    print(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas how I can get working push_back method without checking head and without empty nodes?
My teacher asked after classes, where we was discussing about linked list, if it's possible to do this - no one knew how it can be done.

Comment: What do you mean, you ***can't*** check the `head` is empty?

Comment: @Hogan usually head is pointing to the first element....

Comment: But head is pointer to the first element. My teacher asked after classes, where we was discussing about linked list, if it's possible to do this - no one knew how it can be done.

Comment: may I suggest using a sentry node. That way, there are no special cases, at all. see http://pastebin.com/JAfq6ep1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood your instructors wishes. I believe the instructor desired you not check `if (head)`; Instead check `if (*head)`. They're *not* the same condition.

In your code, `head` is a pointer to pointer. Though you may pedantically wish to check that someone did not pass you a null pointer to pointer, the fact is all you really care about is whether the pointer *it* points to is null (thus the dereference).

And that considerably reduces your code lineage.

```
void pushBack(struct node** head, int value)
{
    while (*head)
        head = &(*head)->next;

    *head = malloc(sizeof(**head));
    (*head)->value = value;
    (*head)->next = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can do this. Thats a very good use for a pointer-to-a-pointer. You can even use `pushBack()` like this:

```
pushBack(&(element->next), 4);
```

if `element` is a pointer to the last element!

If you return the new element from `pushBack`, you can add new elements in constant time O(1), because you don't have to iterate through all the previous elements.

Comment: however, if the code loses the pointer to the first element in the list, then the list is effectively lost (I.E. a major memory leak).  also, checking *head->next without first checking the special case of head=NULL.  Then *head->next will be refering to an offset from address 0.  That will almost certainly lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: I don't know how the code could "lose the pointer", and *if* it happens, **that** is the problem. I didn't write anything about not checking for null..

Answer (score 0):

If head points to the last element in the list then you just say

```
newItem->next = head; 
head = newItem;
```

of course this operations is more often called a "push".  I've not heard the term push back.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a data structures class problem. The answer should be in the reading assignments.

But anyway. I believe the answer is to use a circular linked list. What this is, is a head pointer to an empty node. The empty node marks the beginning AND end of the list. Doing it this way simplifies all of the list operations, because it completely removes the need to operate on the head pointer.

Comment: If it completely removes the need to operate on the head pointer then circular linked list is not answer. My teacher also was saying that there can't be empty nodes in list.